# CSS animation not working in firefox and IE

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

animated header image does not work in Firefox and IE when in chrome is not a problem. I've added -moz- in animation css. http://ayhumaeni.com/

```
#headerimg{
    text-align: center;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: url(images/1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-animation: imag 25s linear 0s infinite alternate running;
    -moz-animation: imag 25s linear 0s infinite alternate running;
    animation: imag 25s linear 0s infinite alternate running;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ;
    transition: height 1s ;
}
```

And this animation

```
@keyframes imag {
    0% { background: url(images/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    20% { background: url(images/2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    40% { background: url(images/3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    60% { background: url(images/4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    80% { background: url(images/5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    100% { background: url(images/6.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes imag {
    0% { background: url(images/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    20% { background: url(images/2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    40% { background: url(images/3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    60% { background: url(images/4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    80% { background: url(images/5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    100% { background: url(images/6.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
}
@-moz-keyframes imag {
    0% { background: url(images/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    20% { background: url(images/2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    40% { background: url(images/3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    60% { background: url(images/4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    80% { background: url(images/5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
    100% { background: url(images/6.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }
}
```

Thanks before :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that both Firefox and IE11 do not like the [`animation-play-state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) being defined in the shorthand [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) property. You have placed it in the correct position for the shorthand syntax, so it is weird behaviour.

Luckily, the `running` value is default, so you can just remove it. If you did want to change the default play state, you can define it as a separate property: `animation-play-state: running`; This works fine.

### Working example with background colours

**Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE11.**

Note that the transition between background *images* cannot be animated; they will just jump from image to image. They can be faded in / out with `opacity` if wanted.

[There doesn't seem to be a need to prefix the animation properties for Firefox anymore.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

```css
#headerimg {
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: #F00;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: imag 5s linear 0s infinite alternate;
  animation: imag 5s linear 0s infinite alternate;
  transition: height 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imag {
  0% {
    background: #FF0;
  }
  20% {
    background: #F90;
  }
  40% {
    background: #F80;
  }
  60% {
    background: #F06;
  }
  80% {
    background: #F50;
  }
  100% {
    background: #F90;
  }
}
@keyframes imag {
  0% {
    background: #FF0;
  }
  20% {
    background: #F90;
  }
  40% {
    background: #F80;
  }
  60% {
    background: #F06;
  }
  80% {
    background: #F50;
  }
  100% {
    background: #F90;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="headerimg"></div>
```